# How can we use 'nc' command to print double sided

Tags: printing

We can use [`nc 192.168.1.3 9100 < file.pdf`](https://retrohacker.substack.com/p/bye-cups-printing-with-netcat) to send a print job to a networked printer. However this prints everything single paged. I would like to print double sided. What are some solutions I could use for this problem?I would expect the solution to be terminal based. I do not intend to install proprietary drivers of the printer.

A naive solution would be to create 2 pdfs; one consisting odd pages and another consisting evens. Once odd pages are completed, we can simply flip the printed bundle and send even pages as the second job. This is a bit troublesome. I am hoping for a more easy solution.

Comment: What kind of printer?  Are you using postscript, PCL, something else ?  You can probably send control codes to set the mode but it depends on the printer type etc.  Another option maybe is to set up the printer such that printing both sides is the default.  Whether you can do that and how is also printer-specific, so it's a good idea to give model numbers and brands as well as current config when having these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 3):

If your printer supports printing from port 9100, it use the [AppSocket or JetDirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetDirect#Protocols) protocol.

The fact that you can use netcat to transfer something to this port is coincidental.

So find out if your printer supports some kind of [Page Description Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_description_language) for print jobs submitted through this port, e.g. [PCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language). Then, find out if it supports a command for printed two-sided (e.g. [duplex](https://www.pclviewer.com/resources/reference/) in PCL).

Then you need to wrap your PDF in a PCL job description and submit it. Google for command line tools for that.

> I am hoping for a more easy solution.

The **easy** solution is to install a printing-system like cups which does all that for you if you configure it correctly. It will also have programs (which, BTW, you can also call from the command line) which will do PCL formatting.

And you don't need to install a printer-specific driver (unless you call generic standards like PCL "printer-specific").